# get system name from application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Hi I am inserting data to mfprintwo table as shown

```
Program.GetConnection().CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    //Program.GetConnection().CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.mfworkorder SET jobstarted=1,lasteditdt=GETDATE() WHERE workorderno=@WorkOrderNo"; // ID: Alan_20130220_002
                    Program.GetConnection().CommandText = "insert into dbo.mfprintwo ( sysserialno,workorderno,seqno,lasteditdt,lasteditby) values(@Sysserialno,@WorkOrderNo,@Seqno,getdate(),@currentuser) ";
                    Program.GetConnection().AddParameter("@WorkOrderNo", workorderno);
                    Program.GetConnection().AddParameter("@currentuser", Program.MfSfcCtrl.User.Logonname);
                    Program.GetConnection().AddParameter("@Sysserialno", product.Sysserialno);
                    Program.GetConnection().AddParameter("@Seqno", product.Seqno);
                    Program.GetConnection().ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In this code @currentuser is the person who login to the application. but instate of that i want to insert the system name in which application running. is it possible? and how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would machine name work? If so, you may do

```
System.Environment.MachineName
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for. Thank you.